# Add checkbox to array with multiple tabs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this problem where I want to add the checkbox to the array with multiple tabs. Each tab has checkboxes. There is no problem when I am only using one tab but with multiple tabs, I cannot put them all in the array because I empty the array first. How to add the checkbox without emptying the array?

This is what I tried so far:

component.ts

```
tabs = ['Sample #1', 'Sample #2', 'Sample #3'];
selected = new FormControl(0);
tabtitle: string = '';
criticalDefects: any[] = ['Helmet', 'Gloves', 'Boots', 'Jackets'];
sampleScore: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {}

addTab() {
  let num = this.tabs.length + 1;
  this.tabs.push('Sample #' + num);
  this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.length - 1);

  this.tabtitle = '';
}
getSelectedCheckbox(tab: number, event: any) {
  this.sampleScore = [];
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  const data = {
    sampleNo: tab,
    criticalScore: 3,
  };
  if (event.target.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      this.sampleScore.push(data);
    }
  }
  console.log(this.sampleScore);
}
```

component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="addTab()">Add Sample</button>
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    <table id="criticalTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Defect Classification</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of criticalDefects; let idx = index">
          <td>{{ item }}</td>
          <td style="width:30% ;">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                (change)="getSelectedCheckbox(index, $event)"
                type="checkbox"
                id="checkboxCritical_{{ idx }}"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="checkboxCritical_{{ idx }}">
                Defect
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

As you can see this code works when I only use one tab. What I want is that I will put them in the array so that I will get the total `criticalScore` group by `sampleNo`. You can check this working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srr4ds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you're resetting your array at every event change and your
document.querySelectorAll() seems to catch only the visible checkboxes. You can log it to see it. Emptying the whole array to refill it doesn't seem like a good option to me. Also, you can't associate the data.sampleNo with your sample number.

I take another approach, you check if the checkbox is checked. If checked you push your data object, if unchecked you remove one item accordly to the sampleNo.

Check the code below I only change the .ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  tabs = ['Sample #1', 'Sample #2', 'Sample #3'];
  selected = new FormControl(0);
  tabtitle: string = '';
  criticalDefects: any[] = ['Helmet', 'Gloves', 'Boots', 'Jackets'];
  sampleScore: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addTab() {
    let num = this.tabs.length + 1;
    this.tabs.push('Sample #' + num);
    this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.length - 1);

    this.tabtitle = '';
  }
  getSelectedCheckbox(tab: number, event: any) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    console.log(checkboxes);
    // 2lines above are unecessary only for awnser purpose
    const data = {
      sampleNo: tab,
      criticalScore: 3,
    };

    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.sampleScore.push(data);
    } else {
      let findIndex = this.sampleScore.findIndex(
        (element) => element.sampleNo == tab
      );
      if (findIndex != -1) {
        //-1 = not found
        this.sampleScore.splice(findIndex, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.sampleScore);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekwnzj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts